# How can we account for gene fold change and their corresponding p-values while clustering gene expression data from different studies?

Tags: statistics, p-value, genetics

Is there a way to perform clustering analysis by taking into account both gene fold change (e.g LFC) and their corresponding p-values?. My intuition is that while performing sample clustering, especially on data originating from different studies in complex diseases, there are some genes that contribute greater to sample variance than others. To take this into account, I am thinking of using both gene LFC and p-value to have a score representative of this fact and subsequently measure their euclidean distances. I have thought of multiplying LFC with -log10 p-value but I am wondering if there a reasonable justification (Statistical or otherwise) to do this?
The recently proposed [Topconfect](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-019-1674-7) package is the closest to this approach using a different method of course, but is there a better justification, if any, to my proposed approach?

Comment: Interesting question, but a discussion like this is suitable for stats.stackexchange.com instead. For what it's worth, my advice is to take a Bayesian approach for any kind of uncertain reasoning; p-values are, I believe, not relevant.

Comment: like Robert mentioned, you can try to shrink your fold changes https://europepmc.org/article/pmc/6581436 such that only those that are significant (or have lower SE) will influence the clustering

Comment: Thank you very much guys. I wanted diverse opinions so I asked the question here too.